# PHP global variable output before foreach loop

Tags: php

I want the words 'AM Appointment' from the Global Variable printing above the foreach loop. I can only echo it out below after the global is set. If I simply echo it above the loop and if there are no results then the title will still be there on its own, I only want it there if there are results. Maybe I'm going about this wrong so any help would be great?

```
foreach
    ($data['Appointments'] as $person){
        if($person['AppointmentType'] == "meeting1")
        {
            $GLOBALS['y'] = "AM Appointment";
            echo $person['FullName'];
        }
    }
echo $y;
```

**This is my output:**

John Smith
Joe Bloggs

AM Appointment

**The output I want is:**

AM Appointment

John Smith
Joe Bloggs

Comment: First of all you don't need `$GLOBALS` to access `$y`, you're already in the same scope. So just use `$y`. Once that's done, you can just store `$name = $person['FullName'];` in the loop, and finally `echo "AM Appointment"; echo $name;` after the loop.

Comment: As well as not needing `$GLOBALS` in this code, it's worth noting that the `$y;` on its own does absolutely nothing; there's no such thing as "declaring" a variable in PHP.

Comment: As described, the answer is trivial: just put `echo "AM Appointment";` at the top of the script. Presumably, however, there is some situation where you don't want to echo it, or where you want to echo something else. Please could you [edit] the question to better explain what is needed.

Comment: I've explained that if there are no results I don't want the title 'AM Appointments' on its own with no listings below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only echo at the end of the loop.
Save the fullnames to a variable until you need them.

```
foreach($data['Appointments'] as $person)
{
    if($person['AppointmentType'] == "meeting1")
    {
        $appointmentType = "AM Appointment";
        $names .= $person['FullName']." ";
    }
}
echo $appointmentType."\n";
echo $names;
```

If your appointmentType can be different and your users need to be sorted based on appointmenttype, you need a different approach:

```
foreach($data['Appointments'] as $person){
    if($person['AppointmentType'] == "meeting1")
    {
        $sorted["AM Appointment"][] = $person['FullName'];
    }
    if($person['AppointmentType'] == "meeting2")
    {
        $sorted["PM Appointment"][] = $person['FullName'];
    }
}

foreach($sorted as $typeName=>$names)
{
    echo $typeName."\n";
    foreach($names as $key=>$name)
    {
        echo $name . " ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Your explanation didnt really mention what needed to be done in the event of multiple types, or no types at all. But I just covered all the bases ^^